# How to put img inline with text

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class = "content-dir-item">
    <p>Text input</p>
    <img src="./images/email.png" class = "mail" alt="img-mail" />
</div>
```

I would put img inline with text using css. How can I do this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Images have `display: inline` by default.
You might want to put the image inside the paragraph.
`<p><img /></p>`

Comment: Doesn't `./` mean in the same directory and `../` mean up one directory?

Comment: The same can also be applied to `<h1>` tag and one can put `<img>` inside it as well to be displayed as `inline`.

Answer (score 16):

Please make use of the code below to display images inline:

```
<img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='somefolder/icon.gif'>
<div style='vertical-align:middle; display:inline;'>
Your text here
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced by the `<div style='display:inline;'>`. There's `<span>` that has this exact meaning

Answer (score 8):

This should display the image inline:

```
.content-dir-item img.mail {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* for older IE */
    *zoom: 1; /* for older IE */
}
```