# Images and h1 tag displayed on the same line CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

Having problems displaying two images and one h1 tag on the same line. I want to align one image to the left and the last two elements on the right. Any tips on how to do that?

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
<img src="meny_knapp2.png" class="meny" alt="meny link">
<img class="hioa" src="logo_hvit.png" alt="HiOA logo">
<h1 class="lsb"> Læringssenteret </h1>            
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
height:120px;
width:100%;
background-color:#ff7f1f;
color:white;
font-size:20px;
display: table;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.meny {
height: 25px;
margin-left:0.5em;
line-height:120px;
}

.lsb {
font-size:24px;
letter-spacing:0.09em;
font-weight:lighter;
display:inline;
}

.hioa {
height: 60px;
float:right;
margin-right:1em;
}
```

Comment: [This thread][1] has something similar. Have a look there :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201756/how-to-put-img-inline-with-text

Comment: please attach image for better, clear and easy understanding

Comment: I can't post images because I don't have 10 reputations

Answer (score 0):

```
.header * {
    float: right;
```

}

```
.header img:first-child {
     float: left;
```

}

```
.hioa {
    height: 60px;
    margin-right:1em;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

please adjust css in class

```
   <div class="header">
    <div style="float:left;width:30%">
        <img src="meny_knapp2.png" class="meny" alt="meny link" width="50"/>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;width:70%">
         <img class="hioa" src="logo_hvit.png" alt="HiOA logo" style="float:left;width:100px"/>
         <h1 class="lsb" style="float:left;width:50%"> Læringssenteret </h1>            
    </div>
    </div>
```