# How do you add a thumbnail photo to a header in ruby on rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to programming and ruby on rails so bear with me! I resized a picture of mine into a thumbnail sized photo and I want to upload it into my header that appears on every page of my website. I placed the image in my `apps/assets/images` folder. My problem is that the icon doesn't appear correctly in the header, instead of to the right of Lions Wrestling it appears below it.

This is the code that I have:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lions Wrestling
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <%= image_tag "Lions.jpg"%>
        </div> 
      </a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201756/how-to-put-img-inline-with-text

Answer (score 0):

Apart from bootstrap-specific styling, you will probably be having an issue with `display: inline` & `display: inline-block`:

---

**CSS**

http://jsfiddle.net/uXEGy/

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://elonmuskblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/elon-musk-blog-photo.jpg" height="150"></div>
    <div class="text">Your text here</div>
</div>

.navigation       { display: block; }
.navigation > div { display: inline-block; }
.image            { vertical-align: middle; }
```

You'll need to make sure your image div has a `display` property of `inline-block`