# Having trouble with my css

Tags: html, css

Can seem to be able to move the image around, I need the image and the text side-by-side and it is, but I would like to be able to move the image done just a little bit so that the middle part or the image is lined up with the text. Right now it is the bottom and no matter what I do it wont move up or down, here is the html for the div and then the css

```
  <div class="img">
    <img src="/image/file/location">
    <div class="imgwording">
        <img src="/image/file/location" class="logoimage">
        Test Text
    </div>
    <div class="sub">
        <img src="/image/file/location" class="mail">
        Test Text
    </div>
    <div class="imagelinks1">
        Training &amp;</br>Events
    </div>
    <div class="imagelinks2">
        Trauma &amp; Gender</br>Projects
    </div>
    <div class="imagelinks3">
        Behavioral Health</br>Resources
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .imgwording { 
   text-decoration: none !important;
   line-height: 1.28; 
   letter-spacing: 1.5px; 
   text-align: center; 
   font-size: 48px;
   padding: 0px 60px !important;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 65px;
   width: 100%;
   font-family: eb garamond,serif;
   color: #fff;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
   flex-direction:column;
   left: -110px;
   display: inline-block;

 }

 .logoimage {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201756/how-to-put-img-inline-with-text

Comment: You can try putting the image as background, or if that fails you can make it absolute position and add padding-left to the div

Comment: The image and text is already inline, but the bottom of the picture is inline with the bottom of the text and Im wondering how to move only the image up or down so that the image is inline with the text still but it looks like in the middle, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have an image and text side by side but the image is lower than it should be. What you could do is add `padding-bottom` to the image CSS to change its position. How many pixels you would want to move would depends on how much higher you want the image to go.

Basically doing:

```
.logoimage {
   width: 50px;
   height: 100px;
   padding-bottom: 5px; /* this could be any value depending */
}
```

Comment: I want to lower the image but keep the text in the same position, already tried this and it just moves the text down not the image, could it be with how Im writing it in the html?

Comment: probably.. I would wrap the text in a p tag or something so that I could have it slightly separated from its parent class. The problem is that the image and the text both are sharing the same parent class so that would be one of the reasons for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Believe after some digging I got it, just need to add 
      position: relative; 
to the .logoimage css

Answer (score 0):

Add vertical-align:middle; to your logoimage class:

```
.logoimage {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
 }
```