# Embed graphics within text in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, latex

I want to embed a small image within the text I am writing on a Shiny html document.

I've looked around and I [found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258299/embed-small-image-within-a-line-of-text) this command `\inlinegraphics{image.jpg}` that works in Latex. I know that to incorporate latex code in Shiny I need to include the relevant latex packages:

```
title: "Random document"
author: "My name"
date: "2 November 2017"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx,calc}
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
```

Apparently, this trick doesn't work. Any suggestions please?

Comment: This looks more like the YAML header from an R-markdown document, not necessarily a shiny document. Are you trying to output to HTML or something else?

Comment: I am using R Studio, and in the tutorial they have about Shiny the process to create a new document is File>New File>R Markdown>Shiny>HTML Shiny Document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this will be to create at `.Rnw` document as following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\inlinegraphics}[1]{%
    \raisebox{-0.3\baselineskip}{%
        \includegraphics[
        height=\baselineskip,
        width=\baselineskip,
        keepaspectratio,
        ]{#1}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}

The following will produce  \inlinegraphics{images/fish.png} an image that is
within text 

\end{document}
```

Following your suggestion, I've adapted this [inline tex image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258299/embed-small-image-within-a-line-of-text/258341#258341) post. It works fine and produces the following pdf.

[image: inline figure]

However, you can't use pandoc to convert this to html (the image is dropped), and you only get the following (with no image).

```
<p>The following will produce <span> </span> an image that is within text</p>
```

Which is not so surprising since pandoc only converts a part of Latex. See
[tex to html post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19928/how-can-i-use-latex-to-build-my-website)

---

So from what I understand, you simply want to embed directly in html. The following code is in a `.Rmd` YAML document.

```
--- 
title: "Random document" 
author: "My name" 
date: "2 November 2017"
output: html_document 
runtime: shiny
--- 

<p>
This is an image that I want displayed inline
<img src="images/fish.png" width="20" height="20" >
inside the text
</p>
```

[image: Inline figure html]
You might want to look at this post [embed image html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201756/how-to-put-img-inline-with-text) for further details.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the follow up question though. But is there a way to adjust the size of the image that is being generated? 
The obvious way for me is to just reduce its dimensions from the source

Comment: Oh, and yes. I was referring to the second part of your code. You did understand correctly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: *"You can't use a tex package within a .Rmd document"*, not correct. http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex_options

Comment: Jespar, the way to control image size is documented in [`knitr options`](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots), as `fig.width`/`fig.height` and `out.width`/`out.height`. If you're talking about a pre-generated `png` or `jpeg`, take a look at [image options in `pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#images).