# How do I put text next to an image?

Tags: html, css

So I've read about a hundred questions and answers on this and clearly I'm doing something wrong here... (Ignore the seriousness of the text, I'm making a loan calculator as an ability test)

I want my image, next to my text on the same line, this is how it currently looks

[image: image depicting GBP icon below body of text]

Here is my relevant code

```css
.topContainer {
  background-color: #0f3759;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.topContainer p {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}

.topContainer img {
  margin-left: 35%;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topContainer">
  <h2 id="headline">Personal Loans</h2>
  <p id="headlineText">18.9% APR Representative on loans between £100,000 to £1,000,000 over 1 to 10 years.</p>
  <p id="headlineDesc">Other loan amounts and terms are available, at different rates. Our loans start at £100,000.
    <br><br>Thinking about a big bet or buying an asset? Need some extra cash to pay off some debts? A Nub Bank personal loan can help make it happen.
    <br><br>Lending and rate are subject to our assessment of your circumstances. Available to UK residents aged 18 and over.</p>
  <img id="cash" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-world-currency-1/432/Flat_Currency_Pound-512.png" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing the margin on the image.

Comment: Look at this and adapt to your exact needs: https://jsfiddle.net/0qowv71p/7/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put img inline with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201756/how-to-put-img-inline-with-text)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As PaulieD suggested, removing your image margin puts it all on one line.

Your problem is that you are asking for the text to take up 60% of the width, the image to take up 40% of the width, and the image margin to take up a further 35% of the width. Obviously this takes up more than 100% of the page so it shunts the extra stuff below. Here's what it looks like without the margin:

```css
.topContainer {
  background-color: #0f3759;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.topContainer p {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}

.topContainer img {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topContainer">
  <h2 id="headline">Personal Loans</h2>
  <p id="headlineText">18.9% APR Representative on loans between £100,000 to £1,000,000 over 1 to 10 years.</p>
  <p id="headlineDesc">Other loan amounts and terms are available, at different rates. Our loans start at £100,000.
    <br><br>Thinking about a big bet or buying an asset? Need some extra cash to pay off some debts? A Nub Bank personal loan can help make it happen.
    <br><br>Lending and rate are subject to our assessment of your circumstances. Available to UK residents aged 18 and over.</p>
  <img id="cash" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-world-currency-1/432/Flat_Currency_Pound-512.png" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

Just as a "best practices with modern HTML/CSS" thing, an easier way to add gaps between elements is to use something like flex or grid. Below is an example using grid, with a gap in between the elements:

```css
.topContainer {
  background-color: #0f3759;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.mainBody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topContainer">
  <h2 id="headline">Personal Loans</h2>
  <div class="mainBody">
    <div class="text">
      <p id="headlineText">18.9% APR Representative on loans between £100,000 to £1,000,000 over 1 to 10 years.</p>
      <p id="headlineDesc">Other loan amounts and terms are available, at different rates. Our loans start at £100,000.
        <br><br>Thinking about a big bet or buying an asset? Need some extra cash to pay off some debts? A Nub Bank personal loan can help make it happen.
        <br><br>Lending and rate are subject to our assessment of your circumstances. Available to UK residents aged 18 and over.</p>
    </div>
    <img id="cash" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-world-currency-1/432/Flat_Currency_Pound-512.png" width="300" height="300">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the best practice comments, very helpful as someone self-learning!

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap its very easy and save you from lot of css coding...

...but if you dont want to use I would say use flex box for it. :) 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You can see my solution for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/osub1g9c/)

```
.topContainer { display: flex; }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
.topContainer {
  background-color: #0f3759;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.contain{
  display: flex;
}

.topContainer .text_block {
  float: left;

}

.topContainer img {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;

}

<div class="topContainer">
  <h2 id="headline">Personal Loans</h2>
  <div class="contain">
  <div class="text_block">



  <p id="headlineText">18.9% APR Representative on loans between £100,000 to £1,000,000 over 1 to 10 years.</p>
  <p id="headlineDesc">Other loan amounts and terms are available, at different rates. Our loans start at £100,000.
    <br><br>Thinking about a big bet or buying an asset? Need some extra cash to pay off some debts? A Nub Bank personal loan can help make it happen.
    <br><br>Lending and rate are subject to our assessment of your circumstances. Available to UK residents aged 18 and over.</p>
      </div>
  <img id="cash" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-world-currency-1/432/Flat_Currency_Pound-512.png" width="300" height="300">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've put the two paragraph tags in a container div, then utilised flex box to put both the paragraph container and the image container on the same line - you can then set any padding or margin on their. As you've set the image width to a percentage, I've also set it's height to auto to allow it to keep it's ratio.